# R: Set every value in group to NA when a value appears more then 75% of the time

Tags: r, na

I have a large DataFrame, which looks like this:

```
ID   GroupID   a   b   ...    
1    001       2   3   
2    001       2   2
3    001       2   2
4    001       2   0
5    001       0   1
6    002       1   1
7    002       2   1
8    002       0   1
9    002       0   1
10   002       2   1
11   002       3   0
...
```

Now I want to set the whole group to NA, when one value appears more than 75% in this Group (because I assume the values are erroneous). 

The result should look like this:

```
ID   GroupID   a   b   ...    
1    001       NA  3
2    001       NA  2
3    001       NA  2
4    001       NA  0
5    001       NA  1
6    002       1   NA
7    002       2   NA
8    002       0   NA
9    002       0   NA
10   002       2   NA
11   002       3   NA
...
```

I know, thats quite a specific question but maybe you can help me.

In case you need the dateset above:

```
ID <- c(1:11)
GroupID <- c('001','001','001','001','001','002','002','002','002','002','002')
a <- c(2,2,2,2,0,1,2,0,0,2,3)
b <- c(3,2,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
DF <- data.frame(ID, GroupID, a,b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be

```
DF %>% group_by(GroupID) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("a", "b"), function(x) if(any(table(x) > length(x) * 0.75)) NA else x)
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   GroupID [2]
#       ID GroupID     a     b
#    <int> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1 001        NA     3
#  2     2 001        NA     2
#  3     3 001        NA     2
#  4     4 001        NA     0
#  5     5 001        NA     1
#  6     6 002         1    NA
#  7     7 002         2    NA
#  8     8 002         0    NA
#  9     9 002         0    NA
# 10    10 002         2    NA
# 11    11 002         3    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `replace` as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

anyPer <- function(x, threshold = 0.75){
  a <- table(x)
  b <- a/sum(a)
  result <- any(b > threshold)
  return(result)
}

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(GroupID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-ID, -GroupID), funs(replace(., anyPer(.), NA))) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
#       ID GroupID     a     b
#    <int>   <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1       1    NA     3
#  2     2       1    NA     2
#  3     3       1    NA     2
#  4     4       1    NA     0
#  5     5       1    NA     1
#  6     6       2     1    NA
#  7     7       2     2    NA
#  8     8       2     0    NA
#  9     9       2     0    NA
# 10    10       2     2    NA
# 11    11       2     3    NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID   GroupID   a   b  
1    001       2   3   
                  2    001       2   2
                  3    001       2   2
                  4    001       2   0
                  5    001       0   1
                  6    002       1   1
                  7    002       2   1
                  8    002       0   1
                  9    002       0   1
                  10   002       2   1
                  11   002       3   0",
                  header = TRUE)
```